# Как увеличить такой шестиугольник?

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно чтобы он был больше по ширине и высоте. Пытался менять ширину, но всё получалось криво. Единственным способом был zoom, но не знаю, насколько это правильное решение.

```css
.cube {
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 4em;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}
.side {
  position: absolute;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background: #47a759;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}
.front {
  transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(42deg) translateZ(60px);
  z-index: 1000;
}
.top {
  transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(42deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(60px);
  z-index: 1000;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.right {
  transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(42deg) rotateY(90deg) translateZ(60px);
}
.left {
  transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(42deg) rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(60px);
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: #479754;
}
.bottom {
  transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(42deg) rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(60px);
}
.back {
  transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(-138deg) translateZ(60px);
}
```

```html
<div class="cube">
  <div class="side front">
    <img src="http://i6.pixs.ru/storage/5/1/0/ico1png_3409525_23310510.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="side back"></div>
  <div class="side right"></div>
  <div class="side left"></div>
  <div class="side top"></div>
  <div class="side bottom">2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Меняйте у класса .side `width` и `height` и везде `translateZ` в одинаковых пропорциях. В данном примере увеличил на 2. Чтоб повернуть меняйте `rotateY`.

```css
div.test {
  xwidth: 100%;
  xperspective: 750px;
  height: 200px;
}
.cube {
  padding: 50px;
  font-size: 4em;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}
.side {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #85cd66;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}
.front {
  transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(62deg) translateZ(100px);
  z-index: 1000;
}
.top {
  transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(62deg) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(100px);
  z-index: 1000;
}
.right {
  transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(62deg) rotateY(90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
.left {
  transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(62deg) rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
  z-index: 1000;
}
.bottom {
  transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(62deg) rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
}
.back {
  transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(-118deg) translateZ(100px);
}
/* cuboid - 100 x 100 x 200 */

.cuboid .front {
  width: 200px;
}
.cuboid .top {
  width: 200px;
}
.cuboid .right {
  transform: rotateX(-40deg) rotateY(122deg) translateZ(150px);
}
.cuboid .back {
  width: 200px;
}
.cuboid .bottom {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-iconic-font/2.2.0/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">

<div class="test test1">
  <h1></h1>
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="side front">
      <i class="zmdi zmdi-wrench "></i> 1
    </div>
    <div class="side back"></div>
    <div class="side right"></div>
    <div class="side left"></div>
    <div class="side top">1.</div>
    <div class="side bottom">2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! А как его немного повернуть? Я везде меняю rotateY(32deg) на rotateY(40deg), но задняя сторона (back) всё равно располагается криво. Буду благодарен если поможете и с этим.

Comment: @Александр обновил пример с повернутым. Для поворота используйте только `rotateY`

Comment: Спасибо, Вы мне очень помогли. Напоследок хотел спросить, почему у меня иконки повернуты не так, как нужно? Сейчас добавлю код в пост.

Comment: Отредактировал пост.

Comment: Лучше верните пост назад и задайте новый вопрос, иначе тот кто найдет ваш вопрос не поймет, что тут произошло.

Comment: Хорошо, так и сделаю

Comment: Вот здесь задал новый вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/566898/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5